# Collection or TableView inside a tableView cell is broken in Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uitableview, mac-catalyst

I'm using UITableViews with cells containing either a UICollectionView or UITableView in them. The cell's height is dependent on the content of the table/collectionView inside it. Think of it like the sections in the Settings app.

This all has been working fine for 2 years now (on iPhone/iPad/Mac running Mac Catalyst), but this week's macOS 12.5 release has caused every cell like this to have some items seemingly missing. However, clicking on a missing item will still have the correct action work, or moving the mouse around/above the missing cells, they will cause the correct content to appear.

Here's a code snippet of a tableView cell with a UITableView in it:

```
class SettingsCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
     @IBOutlet weak var contentTable: UITableView!
     //Height constant of tableView in cell
     @IBOutlet weak var contentTableHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

     private var _type: SettingType = .unknown

     override func awakeFromNib() {
          super.awakeFromNib()
          
          contentTable.delegate = self
          contentTable.dataSource = self
          contentTable.isScrollEnabled = false

          contentTable.register(UINib(nibName: "SettingsRowCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SettingsRowCell")
          contentTable.estimatedRowHeight = 45.0
          contentTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

          layoutIfNeeded()
          contentTableHeightConstraint.constant = contentTable.contentSize.height
     }

     //This is called in the cellforRowAt method in the parent table where it chooses which type of settings section to show
     func updateWithType(type: SettingType) {
          _type = type

          contentTable.reloadData()
          layoutIfNeeded()
          contentTableHeightConstraint.constant = contentTable.contentSize.height
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          if type == .general {
               return generalArray.count
          } else if type == .notifications {
               return notifArray.count
          }
        
          return 0
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
          return 45
     }
}
```

The issue seems to steam from a tableView or collectionView being inside a tableViewCell because happens to all my cells like this.

I've been digging through the code for days, and nothing is out of the ordinary. I never hide any of the cell's content in any scenario, so this isn't the normal reusable cell issue where the content needs to be set back to being visible.

**Does anyone know of the fix this or has any pointers?** Also, these cells work as normal on iPhone/iPad. I've been trying to figure this out for a long time, and any help would be greatly appreciated!